# Crystal reports remove last carriage return

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an address block like such;

123 Fake St
Suburb, VIC
4512

I want to only remove the last carriage return so it looks like;

123 Fake St
Suburb VIC 4512

Im using the following code which i feel is on the right track but it doesnt change the text at all. Totext is in there because without it i get the message "a string is expected here"

`replace({Header.Address},totext(instr(strreverse({Header.Address}),chrw(13))) ,'')`

I feel like i only need a small adjustment on this but i just cant quite figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved elsewhere by;

`StrReverse(Replace(Replace(StrReverse({Header.Address}), chr(10), "", 1, 1), chr(13), "", 1, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the format for the overload of the Replace() function you are using is this.

`Replace (inputString, findString, replaceString)`

You have defined the value of the `findString` argument as this.

`totext(instr(strreverse({Header.Address}),chrw(13)))`

The `findString` argument has a datatype of String, so you had to add the `ToText()` function because the `InStr()` returns an integer value that represents the index of where  the carriage return is found in your reversed string.  You don't need an index for where the carriage return is located in the string for the overload of the `Replace()` function you are using, so you can simplify your `findString` argument to this.

`ChrW(13)`

This will change your original formula to this.

```
Replace({Header.Address}, ChrW(13) ,'')
```

If this still doesn't work, then you may have Line Feed characters in your address data instead of Carriage Return characters.  In this case your formula would be this.

```
Replace({Header.Address}, ChrW(10) ,'')
```

In some cases you may need to replace both Line Feed and Carriage Return characters.  To do this you want this nested version of the formula.

```
Replace(    Replace({Header.Address}, ChrW(10) ,''), ChrW(13) ,'')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response R.McMillan and helping me further understand the replace function. Unfortunately the code you provided is what i had used previously which removes ALL the carriage returns. I only want to remove the last one (preferably with that "," as well)

Comment: Ok, if you have 2 carriage returns that you want to replace with a single carriage return you can use this formula.  `Replace({Header.Address},ChrW(10)&ChrW(10), ChrW(10))`

Comment: No luck with this, didnt change at all. Could I look for the first carriage return from the string in reverse and then remove it?

Comment: There is an overload of the Replace() function that allows you to define the starting index and number of characters for the string you want to replace.  It would be `Replace (inputString, findString, replaceString, startPosition, count) `.  Whether you reverse it or not shouldn't matter, but if you do reverse it, your final output may be reversed still if you don't reverse it again.  I would try it without the reverse first.

Comment: You will also need to use the InStr() function to get the index of the first carriage return for the `startPosition` argument.

Comment: I managed to get the starting position using instrrev, however using the below code just replaces all the text before the postcode instead of just the first carriage return with a space;

replace({Header.Address},chrw(13),'',inStrRev({Header.Address},chrw(13)));